# Conversion Fahrenheit to Celsius using class c

Tags: c++, class

Hello everyone I'm having a problem. I'm fairly new and been stuck trying to solve it.

When I run it the first part where it prints 0 for the Fahrenheit to Celsius is correct but once I input a number it just prints the number I input. I know it probably a simple answer but thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Temp
{
    public:

        Temp(); //CONSTRUCTOR: Sets private variable for Fahrenheit to 32

        void InputF(float F); //Initialize Fahrenheit temperature to F

        void Celsius(); //PRINTS the Celsius temperature corresponding to

        // the private Fahrenheit equivalent temperature

        void ChangeBy(float D); //Changes the private Fahrenheit temperature

        // by D degrees. 

        float Fahrenheit(); // returns the value of the private Fahrenheit temp

    private:

        float Fah; //Fahrenheit Temperature
};

int main() {
    float FF;

    Temp T; // Temperature Object

    T.Celsius(); 

    cout << endl; //Note that the value will be 0 since the private variable is 32. 

    cout << "Input a Fahrenheit temp: ";

    cin >> FF;

    T.InputF(FF);

    cout << T.Fahrenheit() << endl;;

    T.ChangeBy(34);

    cout << T.Fahrenheit() << endl;

    system("Pause");

    return 0;

}

Temp::Temp() {
    Fah = 32;
}

void Temp::InputF(float F) {
    Fah = F;
}

void Temp::Celsius() {
    cout << Fah;
}

void Temp::ChangeBy(float D) {
    Fah = (5.0 / 9) * (Fah - 32);
}

float Temp::Fahrenheit() {
    return Fah;
}
```

Comment: Replaced C tag with C++ tag.

Comment: You are missing the changeby definition.  There should be a void Temp::ChangeBy( float D) { fah = ConvertCtoF(D); } sort of call somewhere beyond the end of this file?

Comment: Your code does not anywhere change Fahrenheit to Celsius. C = (5/9)*(F-32)

Comment: Using a debugger is a lot faster than posting on StackOverflow and waiting for responses.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, invest time now.

Comment: Where are the definitions for the `ChangeBy` and `Celcius` methods?  How were you able to build and run this code without them?  Did you forget to include them in the code you posted?  Also, *please* format your code to use consistent indentation and line spacing; it makes it a lot easier for other people to read and troubleshoot.

Comment: I think I must have didn't paste it correctly sorry.

Answer (score 1):

So, one issue:

```
void Temp::ChangeBy(float D)
{
    Fah = (5.0/9)* (Fah - 32);    
}
```

This method does not do what you say it does in the class declaration; your comment says that it updates `Fah` by the number of *Fahrenheit* degrees passed to it.

If I may suggest the following changes:

First, have `ChangeBy` simply add the input value to `Fah`:

```
void Temp::ChangeBy( float D )
{
  Fah += D;
}
```

Second, have the `Celcius` method do the conversion *and return the converted value*:

```
float Temp::Celcius()
{
  return (5.0/9.0) * (Fah - 32.0);
}
```

Finally, in your `main` function, write the output of `Temp::Celcius()` to the output stream:

```
std::cout << T.Celcius() << std::endl;
```

**EDIT**

I took the liberty of rewriting your code to show what I mean; there isn't enough space in a single comment to really get the point across:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Temp
{
    public:

        Temp( float f = 32.0 );     // slight change here 
        void InputF(float F);
        float Celsius() const;      // note return type, addition of const
        void ChangeBy(float D);
        float Fahrenheit() const;   // note addition of const

    private:

        float Fah;
};

int main() {
    float FF;
    Temp T;

    cout << T.Celsius();  // Note that we output the result of Celsius in 
                          // exactly the same manner that we do for 
                          // Fahrenheit below.
    cout << endl; 
    cout << "Input a Fahrenheit temp: ";
    cin >> FF;
    T.InputF(FF);
    cout << T.Fahrenheit() << endl;    
    T.ChangeBy(34);
    cout << T.Fahrenheit() << endl;
    return 0;

}

/**
 * Slight change here; we're using a member initializer, rather than 
 * assigning Fah in the body of the constructor.  For a simple class
 * like this it doesn't matter, but when you start getting into derived
 * and virtual classes, using this method will make sure things get
 * initialized in the right places and in the right order.
 */
Temp::Temp( float f ) : Fah(f) {
}

void Temp::InputF(float F) {
    Fah = F;
}

float Temp::Celsius() const {
    return (5.0f / 9.0f) * ( Fah - 32.0f ); // use f suffix for float constants
}

void Temp::ChangeBy(float D) {
    Fah += D;    // Update the value of Fah by the input value; the code you
                 // posted isn't using the value of D to update Fah, it was
                 // simply converting Fah to Celsius.  
}

float Temp::Fahrenheit() const {
    return Fah;
}
```

This code builds and runs on a Linux system using `g++` with the `-pedantic -Wall -Werror` flags.

So, I've changed the return type of `Celsius` from `void` to `float`; instead of having `Celsius` print the value, it simply returns the value to `main`.  This way `Celsius` doesn't have to worry about *where* the output gets written (what if you wanted to write to a file instead of `cout`, for example), and its focus is now much narrower.

I also changed the `ChangeBy` function; in the implementation you pasted above, you aren't actually *using* the input parameter `D` to change the value of `Fah`; you're simply converting the value of `Fah` from Fahrenheit to Celcius.

Notice that I also added the trailing `const` qualifier to the `Fahrenheit` and `Celsius` methods.  This indicates that these two methods will not attempt to update any data internal to `Temp`.  It's a good idea to make such "query" methods `const` in this manner; it keeps you from writing code that makes changes where it shouldn't.

Comment: I get two errors when doing changing the return function to fahr to cels equations and also I get a error with the changing the T.Celsius  to an output stream

Comment: @Miahjer: what are the errors?  DId you update both the declaration *and* the definition?

Comment: Return value type doesn't match the function type.

Comment: Then on the main function it says the operators doesn't match these opperands

Comment: @Miahjer: Ah.  There are three possible solutions.  One, you could cast the expression in `Celcius` to `float`: `return (float) ((5.0/9.0) * (Fah - 32.0));`.  Two, you could use a `f` suffix on the floating-point constants: `return (5.0f / 9.0f) * (Fah - 32.0f);`.  Or, finally, you could use `double` instead of `float` for everything (which I would recommend; unless you're really squeezed for space, use `double`).  The problem is that floating-point constants like `5.0` have type `double`, so the result of the expression is `double`.

Comment: I did all three solutions for it and it still says the same thing

Comment: Well I have a question the comment says it has to Print the Celsius temperature corresponding to the private Fahrenheit equivalent temperatures. So I don't have to make a cout statement for the Celsius function?

Comment: @Miahjer: see my edit.  I've slightly rewritten your code to show what I mean.